How to see Experience Points measurement when not immediately having done something that gives them?
I can judge how much EXP I need for the next level by visual fractions when I get EXP, but how do I see how far I have to go for the next skill point?
Do I have to spend all my Skill Points to see my progress? Or does even that not work? Progress to the next Skill Point doesn't seem to appear on the Map menu or anything?
